# Why does this create a FORCE CLOSE

Tags: java, android

```
public class MainClass extends Activity {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        Intent intent1 = new Intent(MainClass.this, SecondClass.class);
        startActivity(intent1);
    }

//---------------------------------------------
public class SecondClass extends Activity {
    ThirdClass thirdclass;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.keyboard);

        thirdclass.Random_Method('A');
    }

//---------------------------------------------
public class ThirdClass  extends Activity {
    public void Random_Method(char NewChar) {

    }
```

Comment: There are closing braces missing..

Comment: He didn't post all the code. Closing braces wouldn't compile. He gets a FC.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ThirdClass thirdclass was never initalized.  Change the code to

```
thirdclass = new ThirdClass();
thirdclass.Random_Method(‘A’);
```

Or, alternatively, do this:

```
new ThirdClass().RandomMethod('A');
```

Also, ThirdClass does not need to extend Activity (and it shouldn't unless you can explain why it needs to).

EDIT:

If it does need to extend Activity then you should be switching to ThirdClass in the same way that MainClass switches to SecondClass with intents. Or rethink the way your activities work so that this TextView happens in SecondClass.  The second would be done like:

```
public class SecondClass extends Activity {
    TextView textView;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.keyboard);
        textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.something);
        random_Method('A');
    }

    public void random_Method(char NewChar) {

    }
```

Comment: I made the change and it still fails. The ThirdClass extends Activity because the Random_Method writes a string to a TextView and I use findViewById.

Comment: Then you should be switching to ThirdClass in the same way that MainClass switches to SecondClass with intents.  Or rethink the way your activities work so that this TextView happens in SecondClass.

Answer (score 1):

I see a couple possible problems:

1. ThirdClass is never instantiated according to your code above.
2. You're calling one Activity's function from another Activity. I don't think that's really possible the way the Android lifecycle works.

Answer (score 0):

ThirdClass hasn't been initialized. You will either need to make Random_Method static or use

thirdclass = new ThirdClass()